# Регулярные выражения в JUnit тестах

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, junit

Допустим, у меня есть такой тест, который проверяет вывод в консоль:

```
public class ArraysAppMainTest {

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        ArraysApp.main(new String[] {});
        boolean test = false;
        test = Pattern.matches("[num:][0-99]", this.log.getLog().toString());
        Assert.assertTrue(test);
    }

}
```

в консоль выводится:

> num:66

Цифры генерируются случайно.
Я не очень понимаю регулярные выражения, но я уже перепробовал разные варианты:
num:[0-99]
num:^[0-99]
и т.д.
Но тест не проходит, что я делаю не так?

Comment: пробовали просто [0-99]?

Comment: пробуйте эту пойдет Вам? `\d?\d`

Comment: Если убрать текст и оставить только цифры, то [0-99] тоже не работает. Но мне надо с текстом

Comment: вообще лучше не использовать регулярные выражения в тестах. тесты должны быть топорные. приветствуется хардокд ожидаемых значений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, так правильно:

```
num:[0-9]{2}
```

`[0-9]`-диапазон символов, но не чисел

`{2}`-количество символов Можно `{1,2}` если число может быть однозначным